# Google Oauth2: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have the following code running on my localhost to try and authenticate with Google Oauth2. After authenticating, it appears to work for a while. Then after a certain amount of time I'm getting this classic error:

```
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
"error" : "invalid_grant"
}'
```

I've looked at the previous times this issue was posted to StackOverflow, but the suggested solutions didn't seem to work for me.

I believe the access token is updated correctly (see code below). I also believe the server clock is synchronized correctly. What am I doing wrong?

---

```
    //$token retrieved from database
    $token = {"access_token":"xxx.xxx_xxxx-xxx","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"1\/xXxXxxxxxXXXxx","created":145490000}

    $google = new Google_Client();
    $google->setAccessType('offline');
    $google->setClientId($client_id);
    $google->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $google->setRedirectUri($client_redirect_uri);
    $google->setAccessToken($token);
    if($google->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $google->refreshToken($token);
    }
    $token = $google->getAccessToken();
    $google->setAccessToken($token);

    //Some Database code to save the new $token
    ...

    $result = new \Google_Service_YouTube($google);
```

Comment: once you get this are you ever able to get it to work again with that refresh token?  I think your refresh token is bad you might want to try and request a new one.

Comment: No, that's the entire issue. The refresh token just appears to stop working.

Comment: Then request a new one

Comment: The error occurs on `$google->refreshToken($token);`

Comment: That is because the refresh token dosent work anymore you need to request authorization again. This will give you a new refreshtoken which will again work.

Comment: Aren't you able to always refresh the tokens every time in order to keep the user authenticated? I can't imagine making some features for a Google App and having to ask the user to re authenticate every time they log in.

Comment: There are several reasons a refreshToken will stop working. I will write you up how it can happen in the morning. I can't type big anwser on mobile app :/

Comment: Also it shouldn't happen all the time you said it works for a while then stops working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two posibple causes for Invalid_Grant

1. server clock not sync with NTP.  (solution fix the time)
2. The refresh token has expired.   (solution request authentication again)

You stated that your code works for a while then stops working.  This makes me think your problem is nr 2.

Reasons why a refresh token will stop working:

1. The user in question has revoked your authentication.
2. If a refresh token hasn't been used for 6 months will automatically expire.
3. Refresh token is based upon the project (Client Id) and the user.  If the user authenticates your application you get a refresh token.  If they do it again you get another refresh token. The first one will still work as will the second.  You can have up to 26 live refresh tokens once the user authenticates your code for the 27 th time you will loose the first refresh token.

To solve your problem you need to try and figure out which of the 3 problems above has caused your refresh token to expire.  I cant really help you much with that its going to require some detective work on your part.

Comment: I think the 3rd case is the most likely, as I'm re-authenticating often to test the code. I guess I should replace the original refresh token with the new refresh token received in the request?

Comment: Every time you get a new refresh toke you should replace the one you have stored with that that way you always have the newest.   You know I hit exactly that problem when I was testing my application did my head in why is it 26!

Comment: In my case the problem was the clock. Synced and now it's ok.